# Ho to extract words between two hyphens?

Tags: r, trim

How to extract all between two hyphens in R

```
   ts = ("az_bna_njh","j_hj_lkiuy","ml_", "_kk")
```

I need to extract  bna,hj,ml, and kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can try:

```
#Data
ts = c("az_bna_njh","j_hj_lkiuy","ml_", "_kk")
#Code
gsub(".*_(.*)\\_.*", "\\1", trimws(ts,whitespace = '_'))
```

Output:

```
[1] "bna" "hj"  "ml"  "kk"
```

Comment: I tried sub("^\\w+_(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", gsub("^_|_$", "", ts)), it worked. But I have a problem. Actually, I need words between  n_ and _a. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @bicton Let me check!

Comment: @bicton Try this code: `ts = c("an_bn_ajh")` and then `gsub(".*n_(.*)\\_a.*", "\\1", ts)` Let me know if that work for you!

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
 sub("^\\w+_(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", trimws(ts, whitespace = "_"))
 #[1] "bna" "hj"  "ml"  "kk"
```

Or another option is

```
 sub("^\\w+_(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", gsub("^_|_$", "", ts))
```

Comment: @bicton can you check your R version.  I am using `R 4.0.2`

Comment: that is the reason, because trimws was introduced or updated in recent versions

Comment: @bicton you said `trimws` is not working.  Not sure how it is working with the accepted solution

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(ts, c("^.*_(\\w+)_.*$" = "\\1", "^_|_$" = ""))
#[1] "bna" "hj"  "ml"  "kk"
```